# How to reduce uCLinux image size?

Tags: image, size, stm32, u-boot, uclinux

I'm using Emcraft STM-SOM uCLinux. It has a 16Mb NOR flash, but I want to use the STM32F4 internal flash which is 2MB. I've made the image and it's about 6 MB. 
 How can I reduce the uCLinux kernel image size?

Answer (score 0):

Build again and remove all the modules you don't need. The size of the Linux image can vary considerably depending on which modules are included at the configuration.